# K-Nearest Neighbor Query in PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis, indexing, nearest-neighbor

I am using the following Nearest Neighbor Query in PostGIS :

```
SELECT g1.gid g2.gid FROM points as g1, polygons g2   
WHERE g1.gid <> g2.gid
ORDER BY g1.gid, ST_Distance(g1.the_geom,g2.the_geom)
LIMIT k;
```

Now, that I have created indexes on the_geom as well as gid column on both the tables, this query is taking much more time than other spatial queries involving spatial joins b/w two tables.

Is there any better way to find K-nearest neighbors? I am using PostGIS.

And, another query which is taking a unusually long time despite creating indexes on geometry column is:

```
select g1.gid , g2.gid from polygons as g1 , polygons as g2
where st_area(g1.the_geom) > st_area(g2.the_geom) ;
```

I believe, these queries arent benefited by gist indexes, but why?

Whereas this query:

```
select a.polyid , sum(length(b.the_geom)) from polygon as a , roads as b  
where st_intersects(a.the_geom , b.the_geom);
```

returns result after some time despite involving "roads" table which is much bigger than polygons or points table and also involve more complex spatial operators.

Comment: I assume your question is how to speed up the query? Can you show us the results of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT ....`? That way we maybe could know what is going on there.

Comment: No, My Question is why Ist this Query is taking even more than 5 times the time taken by 3rd Query above !!

Comment: ok, after about much awaiting, for IInd Query i recieves the following error message :
"out of memory for query result" and query execution terminated. Can somebosy throw light on this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just a few thoughts on your problem:

st_distance as well as st_area are not able to use indices. This is because both functions can not be reduced to questions like "Is a within b?" or "Do a and b overlap?". Even more concrete: GIST-indices can only operate on the bounding boxes of two objects.

For more information on this you just could look in the [postgis manual](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ch04.html#id2628347), which states an example with st_distance and how the query could be improved to perform better.

However, this does not solve your k-nearest-neighbour-problem. For that, right now I do not have a good idea how to improve the performance of the query. The only chance I see would be assuming that the k nearest neighbors are always in a distance of below x meters. Then you could use a similar approach as done in the postgis manual.

Your second query could be speeded up a bit. Currently, you compute the area for each object in table 1 as often as table has rows - the strategy is first to join the data and then select based on that function. You could reduce the count of area computations significantly be precomputing the area:

```
WITH polygonareas AS (
    SELECT gid, the_geom, st_area(the_geom) AS area
    FROM polygons
)
SELECT g1.gid, g2.gid
FROM polygonareas as g1 , polygonareas as g2 
WHERE g1.area > g2.area;
```

Your third query can be significantly optimized using bounding boxes: When the bounding boxes of two objects do not overlap, there is no way the objects do. This allows the usage of a given index and thus a huge performance gain.

Answer (score 19):

Since [late September 2011](http://blog.opengeo.org/2011/09/28/indexed-nearest-neighbour-search-in-postgis/), PostGIS has supported indexed nearest neighbor queries via a special operator(s) usable in the ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT name, gid
FROM geonames
ORDER BY geom <-> st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-90,40),4326)
LIMIT 10;
```

...will return the 10 objects whose `geom` is nearest `-90,40` in a scalable way. A few more details (options and caveats) are in that announcement [post](http://blog.opengeo.org/2011/09/28/indexed-nearest-neighbour-search-in-postgis/) and [use of the <->](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/geometry_distance_centroid.html) and [the <#> operators](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/geometry_distance_box.html) is also now documented in the official PostGIS 2.0 reference. (The main difference between the two is that `<->` compares the shape centroids and `<#>` compares their boundaries — no difference for points, other shapes choose what is appropriate for your queries.)

Comment: A major caveat of these two operators, as it says on the linked postgis reference pages, is that the spatial index will only kick in if one of the geometries is a constant, as in your st_makepoint in the example. This means you can't use these operators with efficient index usage to answer the OP question which involves finding all geometries A near some other set of geometries B.

Comment: Ah, good point. Thanks for raising it. So is @Stefan's answer the "correct" one then, just needing a bit more detail and updated link(s)?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with KNN index and lateral join.

```
SELECT v.gid, v2.gid,st_distance(v.the_geom, v2.the_geom)
  FROM geonames v, 
       lateral(select * 
                 from geonames v2
                where v2.id<>v.id
                ORDER BY v.the_geom <-> v2.the_geom LIMIT 10) v2
where v.gid in (...) - or other filtering condition
```

Answer (score 1):

What you may need is the KNN index which is hopefully available soon in PostGIS 2.x and PostgreSQL 9.1: See http://blog.opengeo.org/tag/knn/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have p point and g polygons, your original query:

```
SELECT g1.gid, g2.gid FROM points as g1, polygons g2   
WHERE g1.gid <> g2.gid
ORDER BY g1.gid, ST_Distance(g1.the_geom,g2.the_geom)
LIMIT k;
```

Is returning the k nearest neighbours in the p x g set. The query may be using indexes, but it still has to order the entire p x g set to find the k rows with the smallest distance. What you instead want is the following:

```
SELECT g1.gid, 
      (SELECT g2.gid FROM polygons g2   
       --prevents you from finding every nearest neighbour twice
       WHERE g1.gid < g2.gid 
       --ORDER BY gid is erroneous if you want to limit by the distance
       ORDER BY ST_Distance(g1.the_geom,g2.the_geom)
       LIMIT k)
FROM points as g1;
```